# Problem converting into PDF with C# at ItemTemplate field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a school assignment but I couldn't seem to retrieve the textbox value under ItemTemplate.

Here are my codes:

ASPX:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="productName"
        HeaderText="Item name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="productLeadTime" HeaderText="Estimated arrival time" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_Quantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>'
                Height="22px" Width="72px" OnTextChanged="tb_Quantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" DataField="quantity"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="productPrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Unit Price" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Total price" />
</Columns>
```

ASPX.CS:

```
PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(gvCartView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count);
foreach (TableCell gridViewHeaderCell in gvCartView.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
    Font font = new Font();
    font.Color = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);

    PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(gridViewHeaderCell.Text, font));
    //pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvCartView.HeaderStyle.BackColor);
    pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
}

foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gvCartView.Rows)
{
    foreach (TableCell gridViewCell in gridViewRow.Cells)
    {
        Font font = new Font();
        font.Color = new BaseColor(gvCartView.RowStyle.ForeColor);

        PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(gridViewCell.Text, font));
        pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvCartView.RowStyle.BackColor);
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
    }
}
Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
pdfDocument.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/PDFDocuments/PO.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

pdfDocument.Open();
pdfDocument.Add(pdfTable);
pdfDocument.Close();
```

[PDFOutput result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4VF6.png)

Please assist... I have tried with Javascript with `OnClientClick` but couldn't work. Can you provide me with a new step? Maybe I did the JavaScript method wrongly. Thank you!

Comment: I have  added an answeri pls check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check type of `ContainingField` of cell is `TemplateField`. If so find textbox for Quantity via [`FindControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol), otherwise get text of cell as you have already used for `BoundField`'s:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gvCartView.Rows)
{
    foreach (TableCell gridViewCell in gridViewRow.Cells)
    {
        Font font = new Font();
        font.Color = new BaseColor(gvCartView.RowStyle.ForeColor);
        var gridText = "";
        if (((DataControlFieldCell)gridViewCell).ContainingField is TemplateField)
        {
            if (((DataControlFieldCell)gridViewCell).ContainingField.HeaderText == "Quantity")
            {
                gridText = (gridViewCell.FindControl("tb_Quantity") as TextBox).Text;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gridText = gridViewCell.Text;
        }
        PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(gridText, font));
        pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvCartView.RowStyle.BackColor);
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Selim, thank you for the clarification. This should be the one that is missing out.

Comment: How do I add other content into the PDF as well? Such as Header and body content? I want to add in some words into the PDF