# Add values (Such as PDF Header and body content) in PDF using iTextSharp c#

Tags: c#, itext

With reference to my previous question, [Problem converting into PDF with C# at ItemTemplate field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788233/problem-converting-into-pdf-with-c-sharp-at-itemtemplate-field)

How do I add other content into the PDF document using iTextSharp? Couldn't find many informations online.

Comment: Do you mean how to add content automatically layout'ed for you by iText, usually in a document created from scratch? Or do you mean pieces of content at positions given by you, usually in an already existing document? And what kind of content?

Comment: I want to add additional values like title: "Invoice" and billing address at the top of the PDF in a structured manner (Just like a normal invoice)

Comment: *"in a structured manner"* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Like an invoice? Invoice details are structured almost the same way and I just want to make an invoice. That's all

Comment: Do you want to create those invoices from scratch? Or do you have a template pdf to fill in?

Comment: I am thinking of styling it from scratch

Comment: Ok, that sounds like you're going to use a `Document` / `PdfWriter` pair of objects into which you feed content pieces, in particular `Paragraph` and `PdfPTable` objects, with additional layout information. Which invoice template do you want to follow?